# Windows10 multi-desktop and multi-screen

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, virtual-desktop

Can someone tell me if in a multi-screen configuration is possible to assign a virtual desktop to a specific 'physical' screen.

Now my configuration is this: Laptop connected to an external monitor.

Now I'd like to keep the laptop screen on its own virtual desktop so it has it's own running programs, its own start-bar,... instead of extending the one I'm using on own screen, and the ability to swap desktop if needed.

Doing so I'll have a 'cleaner' taskbar specific for each screen and no 'mouse overrun' to other screen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible. Virtual Desktop is a really primitive (but still useful) feature.

Here's a little more general info although it does not perfectly fit your question: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180501-00/?p=98645

Multi Monitor is really just one big canvas although I don't know much about the Win32 API and how it's actually all implemented.